# Error : IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm new to python & getting my hands on it so while running my code on problem based on classes & object I get this error : IndentationError: unexpected indent
but can't figure out where I have gone wrong 
Please help me get it & how to solve it
Thanking you in anticipation....
Have a nice day! :>

```
class Get_started:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = str(input('Enter name'))
        print('Hello ',self.name)
        self.rect = self.Rectangle()

    class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self):
        print('In this program we are gonna calculate the area of rectange')

    def get_lb(self,l,b):
        self.l = int(input('Enter length  : '))
        self.b = int(input('Enter breadth : '))

    def show():
        print('Length & Breadth of rectangle are ',self.l,' & ',self.b)
    def cal_area(self):
        self.area = self.l * self.b
            print('Area : ',self.area)

m1 = Get_started('mr_halkat')
m1.Rectangle.get_lb()
m1.Rectangle.show()
m1.Rectangle.cal_area()
```

Comment: You should mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indent everything in the `Rectangle` class, as well as decrease the indent on your `print` statement within the `cal_area` method.

Here's the revised code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

class Get_started:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = str(input('Enter name'))
        print('Hello ',self.name)
        self.rect = self.Rectangle()

    class Rectangle:
        def __init__(self):
            print('In this program we are gonna calculate the area of rectange')

        def get_lb(self,l,b):
            self.l = int(input('Enter length  : '))
            self.b = int(input('Enter breadth : '))

        def show():
            print('Length & Breadth of rectangle are ',self.l,' & ',self.b)
        def cal_area(self):
            self.area = self.l * self.b
            print('Area : ',self.area)

m1 = Get_started('mr_halkat')
m1.Rectangle.get_lb()
m1.Rectangle.show()
m1.Rectangle.cal_area()
```

Answer (score 0):

It said that there is no function inside `class Rectangle`, and wrong indent in `cal_area(self)` function

Did you try to put your code like this:

```
class Rectangle:
     def __init__(self):
          print('In this program we are gonna calculate the area of rectange')
     def get_lb(self,l,b):
          self.l = int(input('Enter length  : '))
          self.b = int(input('Enter breadth : '))

     def show():
          print('Length & Breadth of rectangle are ',self.l,' & ',self.b)
     def cal_area(self):
          self.area = self.l * self.b
          print('Area : ',self.area)
```